# SQL select earlier date (including NULL)

Tags: sql, date, case

I am trying to select the earlier date/time from a two given columns. However, I am running into issues if one of the two columns have a null value.

my thought is
select case when dateTime1 < datetime2 then column1 else column2
end as EarlierDate
from table

However, using the above method will always return null values regardless how I change the greater or smaller sign.

Comment: Include a minimal representative set of data. Also include the SQL implementation as a tag. Per standard SQL rules, `dateTime1 < datetime2` is *always not-true* if *either value* is NULL. What should the result be when one of the columns *is* NULL (this is why included representative data is helpful)?

Comment: That said, this either of these might work: `case when dateTime1 is null or dateTime1 < dateTime2 then column1 else column 2 end`, or even: `case when isnull(dateTime1, '17530101') < isnull(dateTime2, '17530101') then column1 else column2 end` (works fine in SQL Server; using isnull not the standard-COALESCE to both show this and utilize SQL Server's isnull type rules).

Comment: if the other result set is null then the date from the other column should be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have:

`Select Case When Column1 is null then Column2 when Column2 is Null then Column1 When Column1 > Column2 Then Column2 When Column1 < Column2 Then Column1 End As EarlierDate From TableName`